# How do i write a script that keeps reloading and making requests to an endpoint until a specific item is added

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, promise, reload

Im trying to write a script that continuously makes requests to an endpoint  until a certain item im looking for is added to the list located at that endpoint  . So far I have made a promise that , when resolved, returns that item - which is what im hoping happens. However, if it doesnt and the promise is rejected, i need to be able to  rerun the script . How would i do this? Is it a recursive thing ?  Can anyone help?

```
const search = (color)=>{

     let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

         const info = (products) => {                        
                    let arr = []
                     products.map( p => {
                            if (p.color == `${color}`){ 
                            arr.push(p)

                            }
                         }) 
                      arr.length > 0?  resolve(arr[0]):reject("failed")

                }


///api call makes a request that returns all items in the "hats" section 
        const getProducts =  api.getItems("hats", info)


       promise.then(
        res => console.log(res),
        rej=> console.log(rej) 
        )
}

async function trySearch(color)  {
   while (true) {
      try {
         return  await search(color);
      } catch (err) {

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
      }


   }
}

trySearch('Gold')
```

Comment: just write arguments.callee(color)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily keep your function as is and reject it with some legitimate error. Then it's easy to extract a retry method on top of this one

```
const trySearch = async color => {
   while (true) {
      try {
        return await search(color);
      } catch (err) {
        //wait for 0.5s before another attempt, or your computer will cook
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: i tried implementing your method but for some reason it still only runs once  if resolved or rejected. . i need it to keep running if rejected